# Why is the Efimov effect only seen in 3d systems?

Tags: condensed-matter

I have been reading about the [Efimov effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efimov_state), which is that a system of three identical bosons has a particular excitation spectrum, including a bound state, independent of the underlying interaction and even if there aren't any two-body bound states.
[This paper](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v9/n2/pdf/nphys2523.pdf) mentions that Efimov effect can only be seen in $3$-dimensions. Can anyone explain in succinctly terms why occurs this? Is there a similar phenomena in, say, $1$-dimensional systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked abstract does not say anything about the dimensionality of the Efimov effect. In the paper itself, however, we read the following:

> "*So far multi-magnon bound states have been observed with different experimental techniques, but mostly in quasi-one-dimensional compounds.
>   Although the Efimov effect emerges only in three dimensions, the same spectroscopic measurements can be used to observe the emergent Efimov states of magnons.*"

The references are to the early 2000-s, [The three-body problem with short-range interactions by Nielsen et al.](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001PhR...347..373N)
and [Universality in few-body systems with large
scattering length by Braaten-Hammer](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0410417). But the idea goes back to a [1980 paper of Lim and Maurone Nonexistence of the Efimov effect in two dimensions](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.22.1467), who explain the reason as follows:

> "*Now in 3D and as attested by Efimov's construction the Efimov effect arises because of the appearance of an attractive three body force of $1/R^2$
>   character, cutoff at the lower end at $R\sim r_0$ by the nonresonant (or short-range) portion of the pair force, and at the higher end at $R\sim a$ by the resonant part (as determined by the pole term in the amplitude, corresponding to the bound or virtual state of two particles); $r_0$ and $a$  are related to the range of the two body force and the scattering length, respectively. Our analysis indicates that in the 2D trimer an attractive long-range force does not appear. This excludes any possibility of an Efimov effect in 2D.*"

"Any possibility" is a little too categorical, and applies to the standard bosonic setup only. In fact, the first author of the OP linked paper also co-authored [Super Efimov effect of resonantly interacting fermions in two dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4473) and [Semi-super Efimov effect of two-dimensional bosons at a three-body resonance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07532).